# Object is a property of object

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a logic stupid question. I want to do it right and beautiful :)

I use zf2 and when I need to get some bunch of data I write something like this:

```
public function get()
{
    $resultSet = $this->gateway->select();
    return $resultSet;
}
```

and I have a ResultSet of data with fields:

```
data | other_data | product | user
```

but I want "product" and "user" to be object too, but if I will use zf2-hydrator for this it was many sql-queries.

How can I do it right?

Comment: many sql-queries, did you try a limit ? Only "product" and "user", did you try **->columns()** ?

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean. I mean if for each row of the query result I will do in this case also two requests for the creation of objects, it is in my opinion a lot of queries in the end.

Comment: You can always write a Query and Join other tables and their respective columns. This will be one query. Then it is up to you to write a HydrationStrategy to populate the respective values as objects ;) (sadly i can't give you an example as i simply don't use Zend\Db :) )